# What is use of '%s' in xpath

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, nsindexpath, domxpath

I have tried to know the reason in online but i didnt get it.

I want to know the reason why '%s' used in xpath instead of giving text message

I hope some one can help me on this.

see my scenario:
By.xpath(("//div[contains(text(),'%s')]/following-sibling::div//input"))

Comment: By.xpath(("//div[contains(text(),'%s')]/following-sibling::div//input"));

Comment: AFAIK, there is no special meaning of `%s` in XPath. Are using python?

Comment: No , i am using java
Not only this scenario
see below xpath:
//div[contains(text(),'Primary AAL By Location')]/../following-sibling::div//div[contains(@id,'gridview-')]/table//tr//td[%s]/div

Here also he used td[%s]

Answer (score 1):

It's called wildcard.

E.g. you have

```
private final String myId = "//*[contains(@id,'%s')]";

private WebElement idSelect(String text) {
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format(myId, text)));
}
```

Then, you can make a function like:

```
public void clickMyId(idName){
   idSelect(idName.click();
}
```

And call

```
clickMyId('testId');
```

The overall goal of the %s is not using the string concatenation, but to use it injected into a string.

Comment: I have one more doubt i.e

xpath("//div[text()='submission summary']/../..//div[contains(text(),'Status')]/following-sibling::div/div")

What is the use of "../.." in above xpath

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: **..** will take you to the parent of currnet element. i.e It will go to parent of `div[text()='submission summary']`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, there are many locators for web elements which are of same kind, only they vary with a small difference say in index or String.

For e.g., `//div[@id='one']/span[text()='Mahesh']` and

`//div[@id='one']/span[text()='Jonny']`

As it can been seen in the above example that the id is same for both the element but the text vary.

In that case, you can use `%s` instead of text. Like,

```
String locator = "//div[@id='one']//span[text()='%s']";

private By pageLocator(String name)

 {

  return By.xpath(String.format(locator, name));

}
```

So in your case,

```
By.xpath(("//div[contains(text(),'%s')]/following-sibling::div//input"))
```

the text is passed at runtime as only the text vary in the locator.

Answer (score 0):

`'%s'` in XPath is used as String Replacement.

Example:

```
    exampleXpath = "//*[contains(@id,'%s')]"

void findElement(String someText)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format(exampleXpath, someText)));
}
```

So it will replace `%s` with `someText` passed by user.